# Prevent conversion of array to string for an embedded array in a row of CSV in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

The following code

```
require "csv"

CSV.generate({}) do |csv|
    csv << [1, 1, [2, 2], 1]
end
```

Returns

```
"1,1,\"[2,2]\",1\n"
```

Is there away to make it return

```
"1,1,[2,2],1\n"
```

Removing the embedded array conversion to a string

Comment: So instead of one element of `"[2,2]"` you want two elements `"[2", "2]"`?

Comment: @MarkThomas I didn't know it was but that is useful to know. I guess in that case it is almost certainly impossible. Strange because I am sure the d3 documentation implies this is possible.

Comment: The first is correct CSV. If there is a comma in the string, it needs to be quoted.

Comment: @MarkThomas Cheers for the information. Abort the question.

Comment: By the way. I think the down mark is not really warranted. The format of the question is fine and it might have value to some people who might run across the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an invalid CSV syntax, so maybe its better to create your own solution?

Comment: I get `undefined method 'map' for "[1, 1, [2, 2], 1]":String`

Comment: You're asking for something that's only superficially like a CSV but is otherwise totally invalid. Why not just construct it yourself instead of having the CSV module try and do it correctly?

Comment: @Lichtamberg In case the question doesn't get closed (I don't really see why it should) remove the first part and I will mark this as the answer.